# MySQL profiling shows slower query time than PHP microtime difference

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm trying to measure the speed of a particular MySQL query in two ways.

In MySQL

```
SET profiling = 1;
QUERY;
SHOW PROFILES;
```

In PHP

```
$time = microtime(true);
Database::instance()->query(...);
$time = microtime(true) - $time;
```

The time being shown from SHOW PROFILES is ~0.009s (duration).
The time being shown from $time is ~0.001s.

I am very confused because I was expecting the PHP measurement to be slower than the MySQL measurement. It doesn't make any sense. Can anybody explain?

EDIT:
I am aware of the caching and I've tried it with SQL_NO_CACHE but it doesn't seem to make a difference. What I did notice though is that when I restarted MySQL server, the first few profiling attempts are in line with what PHP is reporting. But as I ran the profiling a few more times, there was a sudden jump in duration:

```
1   0.00137900  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count ↵ 
2   0.00138800  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count ↵
3   0.00912700  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count ↵
4   0.00907300  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count ↵
5   0.00878900  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count ↵ 
6   0.00984200  SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(*) AS count ↵
7   0.00895200  SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(*) AS count ↵
```

Breaking down the queries that takes ~0.009s, it appears the jump in time is from creating a tmp table. But the first two times it did this it was really fast (1 and 2). And based on PHP microtime() it's also really fast. Something with the profiler slowed it down after?

```
starting    0.000055
checking permissions    0.000004
Opening tables  0.000013
System lock 0.000050
optimizing  0.000010
statistics  0.000041
preparing   0.000012
Creating tmp table  0.007696
executing   0.000014
Copying to tmp table    0.000317
Sorting result  0.000031
Sending data    0.000007
removing tmp table  0.000423
Sending data    0.000008
init    0.000007
optimizing  0.000011
executing   0.000005
end 0.000003
query end   0.000011
closing tables  0.000002
removing tmp table  0.000004
```

closing tables  0.000006
freeing items   0.000054
logging slow query  0.000002
cleaning up 0.000003

Comment: A lot of things could cause this small a discrepancy. Are your MySQL server and PHP running on different machines? Does the query return a lot of data? It's possible your php client hasn't yet retrieved the data when measuring the end of the query interval.

Comment: They are running on the same machine. And the query returns a count, almost no data at all.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the query becomes cached after the SQL script executes.

So, the SQL script runs the query the first time. The result is cached. Then the PHP script executes. The query is already cached, so the result is retrieved faster.

---

(Ollie Jones)

Try including the [SQL_NO_CACHE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache-in-select.html) option in your query when measuring performance.

E. g.

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(*), SUM(col)
  FROM table
```

---

@ Ollie Jones

But there's even caching on the level of hard disk I/O, which is independent of MySQL's caching.

-ktm

Answer (score 1):

The query cache applies like ktm5124 says but also the profile has to do some other operations on the os and this will slow the query also down in general.

You could test this with the SQL_NO_CACHE parameter and compare the php and mysql result without the profiler.

Comment: I'm leaning towards this answer, as you can see with my edit. The profiler appears to be doing something funny. Are you able to elaborate on your answer?

Comment: SQL_NO_CACHE only says that the result is not stored in cache (but can be still read out of the cache).
So you need to restart mysql and do the same on shell and in php (with the SQL_NO_CACHE paremeter) to have a good result for comparing. And I would rather use a EXPLAIN SELECT than the profiler itself...The profiler is good for analysing slow queries but not a ~0.009 query difference... I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But I am very convinced now that the cause for the discrepancy is due to temporary tables being created on disk. When the PHP scripts run, it creates a new SQL session, so all temp tables get deleted, and it creates temp table on memory. But when I keep my sequel pro session open, and run profiler a few times, it eventually decides to write temp tables to disk. I can't quite confirm this yet cuz I'm not sure how to view temp tables but I believe that would be the answer.